# How can I access the name of the partial from within the layout in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple partial/layout situation where the layout is as follows;

```
<div class="widget">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

and then within my view I am rendering a partial as;

```
<%= render :partial => "my_partial", :layout => "my_layout" %>
```

From within the layout, I want to be able to add the name of the partial (preferably without passing local variables) such that I can customize the widget using CSS.

Ideally, it would be something like this (from within the layout)

```
<div class="widget <%= partial.name %>">
```

Is there anyway to access the name of the partial that is being rendered from within the layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a helper? Something such as:

```
module WidgetHelper
  def widget options = {}, &block
    content = capture &block
    # Add class 'widget' if it's not passed as a class.
    (options[:class] ||= {}).tap {|classes| classes << "widget" unless classes.include?("widget")}
    content_tag(:div, content, options)
  end
end
```

No need to access a file (partial) and no need for local variables.

**sample**

```
= widget :class => "my_custom_class" do
  = @product.comments.first.name
```

Should produce

```
<div class="my_custom_class widget">Block content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial name is something constant. So just write it right in partial

```
<div class="widget my_partial">
```

and why you don't like local variables?

Comment: It's not that I dont like local variables, its more that I wanted to to be via convention rather than specification.